# Antd_dayjs_vite_plugin : TypeError: (0 , import_antd_dayjs_vite_plugin.default) is not a function

Tags: antd, vite, dayjs

At the beginning I got a problem with the french date in the antd calendar. I use vite so I install the antd_dayjs_vite_plugin to switch from Moment.js to Day.js. It worked well but this morning the vite build process is in error. I tried to update the antd_dayjs_vite_plugin version (was 1.1.4) and now I got the same problem when I try to lunch a yarn dev as you can see :

```
$ yarn dev
yarn run v1.22.15
$ vite
failed to load config from vite.config.ts
error when starting dev server:
TypeError: (0 , import_antd_dayjs_vite_plugin.default) is not a function [...]
```

Here is the code in vite.config.ts :

```
import reactRefresh from '@vitejs/plugin-react-refresh';
import antdDayjs from 'antd-dayjs-vite-plugin';
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [reactRefresh(), antdDayjs()],
  server: {
    host: process.env.HOST || '127.0.0.1',
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: [{ find: '@', replacement: '/src' }],
  },
  define: {
    __APP_VERSION__: JSON.stringify(process.env.npm_package_version),
  },
  build: {
        commonjsOptions: {
          transformMixedEsModules: true,
    },
  },
});
```

The problem also appears in antd-dayjs-vite-plugin 1.1.4 version or the 1.2.2. I also already tried to update vite to 3.1 (was in 2.5).

I don't understand the code seems to be exactly the same as the usage in the Readme package.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Just passing by, not an answer :), but you don't need Vite to use another time library : https://ant.design/docs/react/replace-moment, have you considered what antd describe ?

Comment: Hello, I was using vite before. I tried the other solutions but it doesn't work, the french date format is not use. So I tried this solution but with vite instead of [webpack](https://ant.design/docs/react/replace-moment#antd-dayjs-webpack-plugin). Perhaps I should try the previous solutions to use another time library with antd 4.23 version.

Answer (score 1):

Seams that a `default` `export` is expected by `vite.js` (tried to replace import statement with `import {antdDayjs} from 'antd-dayjs-vite-plugin';` without success)

I was able to create a workaround using `patch-package` with the below steps:

- modifiy `node_modules/antd-dayjs-vite-plugin/dist-node/index.js`
- at the very end of that file, add `exports.default = antdDayjs;`
- create a patch for `antd-dayjs-vite-plugin`
- ensure you have the `postinstall` script (refer to `patch-package` doc)